# Attempt using ISBLANK formula not working with conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am attempting to use the `ISBLANK` formula for conditional formatting. What I am wanting to do is if the C column cell is blank then the called out rows in that cell have no formatting. Like this:

If the highlighted cell is blank then the green outlined cells have formatting that is modified.

[image]

I added in a supplementary formula to try and get this to work, but still, the first formatting rule should still work.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Would `=$C6=""` work for you?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad It does not. Columns G-J are still showing.

Comment: Try changing the "Show formatting rules for:" drop-down in the "Conditional Formatting Rules Manager" to "This Worksheet" to see if there are other rules on the sheet interfering with these rules. Also, when selecting "Current Selection", be sure you have selected the row with the problem. Additionally, make sure you don't have blank spaces in column C on the offending row.